# TypeError: $(...).load(...).appendTo(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new in JavaScript and  jQuery. I have function where I am opening POPUP box on click and I am passing content value using `href` link.

This pop is working fine to me but sometime(after making few other calls on same page) when I click on link to open this POPUP I am getting script error in console and POPUP is starched (Showing whole page which is pass in herf instead POPUP box)  :

**TypeError: $(...).load(...).appendTo(...).dialog is not a function
$('', {**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"; />
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>;
<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('a#vehicle').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.mask').width($(document).width());
        $('.mask').height($(document).height());
        $('.mask').show();
        $('<div/>', {
            'class' : 'myVehicleClass',
            'id' : 'link-' + ($(this).index() + 1)
        }).load($(this).attr('href')+ "?random=" + Math.random()*99999).appendTo('body').dialog({
            'title' : "Select a vehicle",
            'width' : 600,
            'height' : 500,
            close : function(event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $('.mask').hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I checked this issue on StackOverfolw and there are many related question on there but no worked to me :(

Comment: did you include the jquery ui library

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comment, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29058703/edit) button instead.

Comment: Thanks niese. Please help if you have clue?

Comment: Looks like it should work providing jQuery UI is loaded. But remember that the content delivered by `.load()` will arrive asynchronously. It is guaranteed not yet to be in place when `.append(...).dialog(...)` execute.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran into a similar error message where ".dialog is not a function". The problem for me was indeed that jQuery UI was not loaded.